# ui-Router templateUrl not able to find $templateCache template in app-release.js

Tags: angularjs, gulp, angular-templatecache

I use `Gulp-angular-templatecache` to cache my html templates into **templates-cache.js** and then I use `Gulp-browsify` to compile my **app.js** file to generate **app-release.js** file which contains all the code from both app.js and templates-cache.js files.

app.js includes all the dependencies including the generated **templates-cache.js** file but `ui.route` is unable to call the html files on `templateUrl` I followed angular guide at [https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache](http://Angular%20Guide) but I am still unable to find the issue.

**app.js**

```
import angular from "angular";
import uiRouter from "@uirouter/angularjs";
let template = require("../../templates-cache.js");

let app = angular.module("app", [uiRouter]);

app.config(function ($stateProvider) {

    let Default = {
        name: "default",
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: "home.html"
    };

    let Home = {
        name: "home",
        url: "",
        templateUrl: 'home.html'
    };

    $stateProvider.state(Home);

});
```

**app-release.js**

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider) {

    var Default = {
        name: "default",
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: "home.html"
    };

    var Home = {
        name: "home",
        url: "",
        templateUrl: 'home.html'
    };


    $stateProvider.state(Home);
});


},{"../../templates-cache.js":77,"@uirouter/angularjs":1,"angular":75}],77:[function(require,module,exports){
'use strict';

angular.module('template', []).run(['$templateCache', function ($templateCache) {

  $templateCache.put('home.html', '\n<div class="largeText">My Angular App</div>\n\n');

}]);
```

**Error in Chrome**
[Error in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oF4oc.png)

Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here. I am not injecting `template` that is generated by gulp-angular-templatecache.

**Fix**

```
let app = angular.module("app", [uiRouter, "template"]);
```